# Gson converts the HashMap<Integer> to HashMap<String> inside my Object

Tags: java, json, gson

I have an object which has a map inside it:

```
MyDTO 
   HashMap<Integer>
```

Now when I convert my MyDTO to JSON (with Gson), and then back from JSON to MyDTO what I get is `HashMap<String>`.

I convert from JSON back to object like this:

```java
MyDTO dto = gson.fromJson(json, MyDTO.class);
```

How can I force it to convert/keep the Map inside the DTO as `Map<Integer>` and NOT as `Map<String>`?

Here is my Object:

```java
public class MultiSeriesTimebasedChartDTO implements Serializable  { 
    LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<Number>> data;
}
```

Here's how I convert my JSON back to object:

```java
multiSeriesTimebasedChartDTO = gson.fromJson(json, MultiSeriesTimebasedChartDTO.class);
```

And here is the result (in screenshot), which were Numbers but now are Strings. I needed them back as Numbers.

[image: Debugger screenshot showing object values]

So looking for a clean approach for this.

I can definitely iterate over it, change every number from string back to number, and replace it... But I was thinking may be there is some other better way of oing it.

Comment: as Map<Integer> and not as Map<String>  , because after i convert back to my object from json , The Map inside my object which was type Integer , Its not converted to a type String , So everything inside my map is now String ,which were integers actually

Comment: Show your DTO and source JSON

Comment: `Map<Integer>` is not a valid Java type, since a `Map` requires **2** type arguments. Did you mean `Map<String, Integer>` or perhaps `Map<Integer, Integer>`? Normally, a `Map` is converted to a JSON Object, and since a JSON Object is a set of name/value pairs, the keys in the `Map` are converted to strings, because JSON property names *must* be strings. Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: I added details in my question

Comment: can you show your map .put( ) line(s) ? Or your data =  anything  line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no "`HashMap<Integer>`" whatever that could be, you have `ArrayList<Number>`, and that is what GSON has to prepare for:

> ```
> public class MultiSeriesTimebasedChartDTO implements Serializable{
>   LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<Number>> data;
>                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> }
> ```

Also, you don't have `String`s what you complain about, those are `LazilyParsedNumber`s,

> [image]

And while it really stores the value as a string, that class indeed is a [`Number`](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/ceae88bd6667f4263bbe02e6b3710b8a683906a2/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/LazilyParsedNumber.java#L26). You don't have to worry about its private member variables.

> ```
> public final class LazilyParsedNumber extends Number { // <= extends Number
>   private final String value;  // <= this is what you see in the debugger
> ```

But that is just the explanation about what's there now. If you want GSON to produce you a list of `Integer`s, you should simply write that:

```
public class MultiSeriesTimebasedChartDTO implements Serializable{
  LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> data;
}
```

remember that GSON can only analyse the declaration of the class, it can't guess if you later ensure that all those generic numbers are integers.

Answer (score 1):

The values are still `java.lang.Number`s after the JSON is parsed. However, because your field has the type `LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<Number>>`, Gson uses its internal type [`LazilyParsedNumber`](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/LazilyParsedNumber.java) because it cannot know as which specific type you want the `Number`s to be parsed. LazilyParsedNumber acts as a wrapper for the JSON string representation so you can call the respective `Number` method to parse the value.

LazilyParsedNumber should suffice if you are only retrieving its `intValue()`, `doubleValue()` ..., but if want to compare it with other Numbers it wont work since LazilyParsedNumber is only equal to itself.

Since your question mentions that the Map contains `Integer` values, the easiest solution would be to change the type of the DTO field:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>
```

This way Gson knows the exact number type you want and can properly deserialize the JSON numbers as Integers.